# Difference in a mathematical expression with and without parentheses

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the difference between $(-1)^{k-1} \, (2k-1)$, with parentheses, and $(-1)^{k-1} \, 2k - 1$ without the parentheses.

In summation notation let's assume that the first formula would give this sequence: $ 1 -3 + 5 - 7 + 9 + \cdots + 801$.  What would the second formula give?

Comment: The difference is that in 2nd case you firstly compute $(-1)^{(k-1)} * 2k$ and then subtract $1$ from the result.

Comment: The second expression is $2-4+6-8+\cdots +802-1$ , every summand increases by $1$ in absolute value and at the end we subtract $1$.

Comment: ahaaa now I understand. this shows the power of parenthesis. thanks guys

Comment: If the first sum has value $S$ , the second has also value $S$ , if $k$ is odd and $S-1$ , if $k$ is even.

Comment: @Peter makes sense thank you sir